# Python errors with simple code

Tags: python, django

I feel embarrassed just writing this question.

I've just installed python 3.4 and django 1.8

If I enter the python interpreter and enter:

```
>>> import django    
>>> print(django.get_version())
```

I get the answer 1.8 which is fine.

If I create a file django.py and in it enter:

```
import django
print(django.get_version())
```

Two things happen:

1. When I run it I get the error

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "django.py", line 1, in <module>
       import django
     File "C:\Python_Mongo\django.py", line 2, in <module>
       print(django.get_version())
   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_version'
   ```
2. It then creates a cache folder `__pycache__` and if I simply start python interpreter and enter the command: `import django` it runs my `django.py` file! (any other command is fine).

Please help :(

Answer (score 6):

You have a file `django.py` in your local directory, it masks the Django package. Rename it to something else.

See your traceback:

```
  File "django.py", line 1, in <module>
    import django
```

Note how the line `import django` is run from a file named `django.py`?

Comment: ah, how embarrassing :), something I never thought of. btw, thanks for the edit, stackoverflow editor was driving me crazy with >>> removing itself and '2.' changing itself to '1.' on rendering

Comment: @Neil: `>` is syntax for a blockquote, and lists auto-number, but if the list sequence is broken the numbering starts at 1 again.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing surprising. If you invoke the `import anything` in a file named `anything.py` it will import itself.

Python's import path resolving searches current directory first and only after it looks for the module in system path.

Comment: thanks, I will remember that. Glad things are working for me now.